# What simple fixes are there to an overly vigorous sliding door?

Tags: doors

I have a sliding interior door. It slides fast. When it closes, it results in an elastic collision, and this causes the door to reopen, and make an awful sound. I know you can get "smart" (pneumatic, or springed) door slides. I looked at weather stripping, but that just makes the door open itself up (because they push up against each other).

[image: Vigorous Door]

Comment: Assuming the track at the top of the door is utilizing ball-bearing wheels you could attach layers of vinyl tape (or any similar material) between the wheels and the sides of the track. Thus lessening the space between the sides of the track and the rollers. This would increase friction and cause the door to be more resistant to movement.

Comment: Didn't help. It either got into one of two modes - one, where I would close it, and I'd have to close it all the way by hand, or the other, which is just as bad in my opinion, or it wouldn't do anything.

Comment: I like the animation.